# Quicksand question in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, select, pageload, quicksand

I am using the Quicksand jquery scripts on an HTML page and using simple select controls:

```
<select name="sort" style="vertical-align:middle;" id="cboSort">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Low to High</option>
    <option value="2">High to Low</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to have the quicksand scripts run on page load but I have no idea how to do that, I am learning javascript so I am a bit confused. Basically I want the items to be already sorted from Low to High on page load. This is a simple one page website.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was fixed using autoselect and variable switch

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code you want to run in jQuery's `$(document).ready()` construct:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code goes here...
});
```

This will only run once the whole page is loaded.

Comment: both answers are good, but because the sort is in a jquery script file I am going to try this one when I get home. Now quick qeustion. If I do this,will I still be able to use the select controls to run the quicksand scripts after the page has loaded?

Comment: I wasn't too familiar with quicksand, but after a quick look at the demo code here: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html it appears that the sort functionality is bound to your select element's onchange event. In that case, you could simply fire the element's `change()` function after running the quicksand scripts to perform the first sort. e.g.: `$('#cboSort').change() ;`

Comment: Gus, I placed the sort code in a js file so it is outside the page and contained within the main script function. I tried the $(document).ready(function() but it didnt run on load, did I forget to do something else. Does a reference need to be placed within the body tag

Comment: Wait it did run the script however for some reason it did not sort like it was supposed to

Comment: Gus it is failing on this line // attempt to call Quicksand on every form change      $('select').change(

Comment: Gus ok figure that issue out, however, the sorting and filtering will not work now after the page is load, I need to be able to apply filtering and sorting after the page is load as well. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sortFunction() {
//logic
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="sortFunction()">
<select name="sort" style="vertical-align:middle;" id="cboSort">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Low to High</option>
    <option value="2">High to Low</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

try that, the other answer works too